# Read from Windows Phone Local database

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have a database in my windows phone app. From a Table I need to select some rows. I need to apply more than one Where conditions in my query. How can I write such a query?

My table contains Username, DocumentId, FileType, FileLocation, FileSize etc..

I need to select rows using Username, DocumentId and FileType. How to write the query for that?

Now I am using the following code :

```
using (DocumentDataContext DocDb = new DocumentDataContext(strConnectionString))
{
    IQueryable<Document> DocQuery = from Doc in DocDb.Documents where Doc.UserName == txtName.Text select Doc;
    Document Docs= DocQuery.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I can select one document using this query. I want to select all rows satisfy the conditions. Can I do this in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. You can extend your `where` condition using standard or/and keywords:

```
from Doc in DocDb.Documents
where Doc.UserName == txtName.Text && dic.FileType == "some type" && Doc.UserName == "some name"
select Doc;
```

To get more than one row use [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) instead of [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482). It returns a list of elements containing the query results:

```
var Docs= DocQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But use '&' instead of 'and' in the query for proper working, otherwise the following error will occur "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause." I asked this question because of this error. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

To select more than one document and to apply more than one condition in "WHERE" clause, I made some changes in the code as follows

```
IList<Document> DocumentList = null;

using (DocumentDataContext DocDb = new DocumentDataContext(strConnectionString))
{
    IQueryable<Document> DocQuery = from Doc in DocDb.Documents where Doc.UserName == txtName.Text & Doc.DocumentId == docId & Doc.FileType == fileType select Doc;
    DocumentList = DocQuery.ToList();
}
```

In the query I used "AND" first to add more condition in "WHERE" clause. When I changed "AND" to "&" it works properly, and use an IList<> for getting more than one record